# How to loop through form fields in Sensio Generator Bundle

Tags: symfony, twig, crud

I have overridden the Sensio Generator Bundle for CRUD in order to better suit my needs.

What I would like to do is to be able to loop through the entity fields.
It is done by default in show.html.twig but not in new and edit views.

When I implement the same logic in new.html.twig.twig it doesn't work though it does for edit.html.twig.twig.

```
{#app/Resources/SensioGeneratorBundle/skeleton/crud/views/new.html.twig.twig#}

{% for field, metadata in fields %}
    {% if field not in 'id' %}
        {{ '{{ form_row(edit_form.' ~ field ~ ')}}' }}
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

When running the generator, the error is: Variable "fields" does not exist in "crud/views/new.html.twig.twig" at line 9

Comment: The "new" view generator (https://github.com/sensiolabs/SensioGeneratorBundle/blob/master/Generator/DoctrineCrudGenerator.php#L242-L256) doesn't pass the fields to the template render. I assume you would need to write the `renderFile` method to include `'fields' => $this->metadata->fieldMappings` but, obviously, this would involve having to extend the actual class.

Comment: And you had already worked this out. Poo.

Comment: Yes. Thank you for your answer. Writing your issues sometimes helps in finding the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, in fact it is an issue in Sensio Generator Bundle.
In the file: sensio\generator-bundle\Sensio\Bundle\GeneratorBundle\Generator\DoctrineCrudGenerator.php the generateNewView function is missing a paramter. It is not passing the fields as opposed to generateShowView.

Here is the comparison:

```
protected function generateNewView($dir)
{
    $this->renderFile('crud/views/new.html.twig.twig', $dir.'/new.html.twig', array(
        'bundle'            => $this->bundle->getName(),
        'entity'            => $this->entity,
        'route_prefix'      => $this->routePrefix,
        'route_name_prefix' => $this->routeNamePrefix,
        'actions'           => $this->actions,
    ));
}
```

versus

```
protected function generateShowView($dir)
{
    $this->renderFile('crud/views/show.html.twig.twig', $dir.'/show.html.twig', array(
        'bundle'            => $this->bundle->getName(),
        'entity'            => $this->entity,
        'fields'            => $this->metadata->fieldMappings,
        'actions'           => $this->actions,
        'route_prefix'      => $this->routePrefix,
        'route_name_prefix' => $this->routeNamePrefix,
    ));
}
```

I'll try to post this as an improvement.

Comment: Posted here: [gitHub](https://github.com/sensiolabs/SensioGeneratorBundle/issues/325)

Comment: Issue has been fixed : https://github.com/sensiolabs/SensioGeneratorBundle/pull/401